# The meaning of じゃないんだろう in this context 賊達の目的は略奪で、殺しじゃないんだろう

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

When reading, I met this sentence which describes MC's thoughts during a battle with bandits:

> 賊達の目的は略奪で、殺し**じゃないんだろう**。
>
> > My *guess*: "I think the bandits are after looting, not killing."

What is the meaning of the じゃないんだろう part?

Comment: のだろう is just a question tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the sentence is correct. I'm not sure which part of じゃないんだろう you mean specifically though.

「殺し」 means 'killing' as you have pointed out. 「じゃない」, means "not," which I'm sure I don't need to tell you. 「ん」 is an abbreviation for 「の」 in this sentence. 「だろう」means something like, "It seems" or "I'm sure," among other things (take your pick here).

「のだろう」is used here because it is preceded by the nai stem (未然形). According to [goo dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/#jn-171991) it means to "emphasize" or "make sure."